# How to append list of data to dropdown with combobox class

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can't append data into dropdown using jQuery

JS:

```
var options = '';
options += '<option value="0">Select Client</option>';
$.each(result, function(i, result) {

  options += '<option value="' + result.branchId + '">' + result.branchName + '</option>';

});

$("#branchId").append(options);
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control  combobox" asp-for="branchId" onchange="getClientDetails()">
  <option value="-1">Select Item </option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is _result_ ?!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the HTML has an ID that matches your jquery selector:

```
<select class="form-control  combobox" id="branchId" onchange="getClientDetails()">
  <option value="-1">Select Item </option>
</select>
```

```js
const result = [{branchId:1, branchName:'one'}, {branchId:2, branchName:'two'}];
let options = '';
options += '<option value="0">Select Client</option>';
$.each(result, function(i, result) {

  options += '<option value="' + result.branchId + '">' + result.branchName + '</option>';

});

$("#branchId").append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control  combobox" id="branchId" onchange="getClientDetails()">
  <option value="-1">Select Item </option>
</select>
```